# Transmission not working as expected in cycles Blender Guru donut tutorial

Tags: materials

I am brand new to Blender an was following Blender Guru's 2.8 Donut tutorial. He said that one way to get a material to look like glass is to turn transmission up to 1.00. This worked for the most part, but the glass on the main frame of the cup has this weird texture to it in some places. When I move the camera around, the place where the glass is clear shifts so that it is always on the other end of the glass, which leads me to believe that because the light is going through two pieces of glass, it gets distorted. Any way I can fix this?
[image]